# How can I authenticate against an MVC Core app from a Chrome extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome-extension

In my extension manifest I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "https://localhost:5001/"
]
```

In my Startup.cs ConfigureServices method I have:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001/",
                            "chrome-extension://mdgfojbohoeindggojmfcphhobepgcbk/");
    });
});
```

And in the Startup.cs Configure method I have:

```
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Having a button call `window.open('Url_of_signin_page')`, then redirecting back to the original page once the user has signed in. This sets the auth cookie, and when I browse to an endpoint that requires authentication manually it works. However, `XMLHttpRequest` calls don't send the cookie.
2. Using AJAX to fetch the HTML of the signin form and adding it as a div to the current page the extension is running on. Problem here is the MVC form tag helper omits the host from the form action attribute, and since the page it's on is no longer on the same domain as the app it doesn't work. If I specify the form action instead of using the tag helper then anti-forgery token validation fails, even though I've added `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` explicitly to the signin form.

Ultimately I want the user to be able to signin to the MVC Core app and have the extension be able to make authenticated requests to that MVC Core app. Is that possible and if so, how?

Edit to add: I am setting withCredentials=true on the XmlHttpRequest.